# Networking on OS x - determining if "en" is wired/wireless

Tags: java, macos, networking

I'm building a Java application that will run cross-platform, meaning it should run on OS X. Unfortunately, I'm kind of new to the Mac world.

One of the things the application needs is a list of networking interfaces and a little bit of information about them. Because I'm working with Java, I only have access to a limited amount of information, and then must rely on running command line apps and parsing their output.

When I run on Win / Linux, it's easy. When I see a network called "wlan" with a number, I know that it's wireless. "eth" means wired.

OS X makes things more difficult. It seems to call everything "en". I realize that en0 is "almost always" going to be wireless, but how do I know for sure? And what happens if there are more interfaces? Thunderbolt turns into ethernet, and I can hang lots of things off of USB.

If I see en0, en1, en2, en3, how do I know what's wireless and what isn't?

Comment: What is the underlying reason you need to know this?

Comment: The application tests various security issues with networks. One of the first things we need to do is show the user the list of network interfaces he's connected to, Knowing whether each one is wired or wireless is important.

Comment: The output from `system_profiler` contains this.

Answer (score 0):

You can also parse the output of

```
networksetup -listallhardwareports
```

on macOS.